# sticky youtube video not working on chrome and working on Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube-api

I'm doing sticky video on the page, when you scroll down, it will be minimized and sticked to the page. the following code works on safari and Firefox but doesn't work on chrome!

I'm using jquery-1.7.1.min.js and "jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" and it works on Safari and Firefox!

and if I changed the jquery to "jquery-1.9.0.min.js" it doesn't work on safari and chrome but still working on firefox!

Did the jquery & Jquery ui version can be the reason behind this issue in chrome?

HTML:

```
 <!-- video -->
 <div class="content-header">
 <!-- The YouTube video -->
  <figure class="content-media content-media--video" id="featured-media">
       <iframe class="content-media__object" id="featured-video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ir4lKwFLMCY?enablejsapi=1&rel=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" width="400px"></iframe>
</figure>
```

JS:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* sticky viedo */
jQuery(function(e) {
  function s(e) {
    var s = 1 === e.data,
        a = 2 === e.data,
        o = 0 === e.data;
    s && (i.removeClass("is-paused"), i.toggleClass("is-playing")), a &&     (i.removeClass("is-playing"), i.toggleClass("is-paused")), o && i.removeClass("is-playing", "is-paused")
}
    var a, o = e(window),
    t = e("#featured-media"),
    i = e("#featured-video"),
    n = t.offset().top,
    l = Math.floor(n + t.outerHeight() / 2);
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    a = new YT.Player("featured-video", {
        events: {
            onStateChange: s
        }
    })
}, o.on("resize", function() {
    n = t.offset().top, l = Math.floor(n + t.outerHeight() / 2)
}).on("scroll", function() {
    i.toggleClass("is-sticky", o.scrollTop() > l && i.hasClass("is-playing"))
})
});

</script>
```

CSS:

```
/* Sticky Youtube */
 #featured-video {
  transition: width .2s ease-in-out, height .2s ease-in-out, transform .38s     ease-in-out;
}

#featured-video.is-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: auto;
  max-width: 280px;
  max-height: 158px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 158px;
  z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: Try the latest jQuery 3.2.1 and the latest jQuery UI 1.12.1

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne  for your suggestion, I tried  jQuery 3.2.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1, still the same not working on chrome, working on safari and firefox also!

Comment: IMO jQuery 2.2.2 and jQuery UI 1.12.1 are the most stable try that combo.

Comment: @zer00ne still the same!

Comment: That's strange, if Chrome has a bug, Safari follows suit since they are both webkit. What's more bizarre is that Firefox behaves correctly like Safari.

Comment: @zer00ne actually it looks so weird for me! I made another solution with the "$(window).scroll(function() { …. } " I will try to research this case later on as it's very time consuming and no debugging data to guide us!